# How to show starred subsections in minitoc and not in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I've the `main.tex` and `chapter1.tex`, `chapter2.tex`, ... For each chapter I have a minitoc.

In principal toc I want to show chapters and sections (have I to star the subsection, right?). In each minitoc I want to show also all the subsections. How to do?

MAIN.TEX

```
...
\usepackage{minitoc}
..
\dominitoc
..
\tableofcontents
..
\setcounter{mtc}{8}
\input{./Chapters/Chapter1}
...
```

CHAPTER1.TEX

```
..
\minitoc
\section{Introduction to something}
\subsection*{What is something}
...
```

I tried lot of combination, I read lot of websites and guide, I spent lot of time.
Thanks in advance for every little help!

Comment: Don't use starred subsection. Set the counters tocnumdepth and secnumdepth correctly (minitoc imho has such counters for the minitocs too.)

Comment: I solved by inserting
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
without using star.
Many thanks!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Please make that an answer

Answer (score 2):

Don't use starred subsection. Set the counters `tocnumdepth` and `secnumdepth` correctly (`minitoc` imho has such counters for the minitocs too.)